# how do I make it impossible to type into my textarea tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want my second text area tag to only be for outputting text and not for typing in, but I don't know how too, I tried setting the type too "output" but unfortunately that didnt work. thank you for taking the time to read this, please find code below. I also want to add that I dont know why my button is under my text area, on my usual website the button is next to the text area.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textArray = text.split(" ").sort();
    var output= document.getElementById('output');
    output.value = textArray.toString().replace(/,/g," ");
 }

 function maFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("output");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
```

```css
body {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.txt {
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    border-width: 2px;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.text {
    border: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 18px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 630px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
}

.asci {
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #4CAF50;
    outline: none;
    height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);*/
}

.ascii {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 660px;
    width: 564px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    resize: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: none;
}

.button {
    background: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

::selection {
  color: black;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>alphabetical order machine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alphabetical.css">

</head>
<body>
    <form class="txt">
        <textarea class="text"  id="input" type="text" placeholder="type your text here" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea>        
    </form>
    <form class="asci">
        <textarea class="ascii" id="output" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
        <input class="button" type='button' value="copy" onclick="maFunction()">
    </form>
    <script src="alphabetical.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add the `readonly` attribute: `<textarea readonly="readonly" ...>`

Comment: The `type` attribute on `<textarea>` elements does nothing.

Comment: @Pointy he does not seem to be using XHTML so `<textarea readonly... >` should be enough no need to write the full attribute when is a boolean attribute.

Comment: @PabloRecalde I would of course just use `readonly` but I've gotten into the habit of doing that to stave off comments from excessively pedantic SO users :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your teaxtarea readonly

```
 <textarea readonly class="ascii" id="output" type="output" placeholder="your alphabetized text will appear here"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two attributes that should work on any html input to achieve this behaviour:

- [Readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly) as the other answer has pointed out.
- [Disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled): which will do as readonly but also, it won't include the field when sending the form back to the server (if that's the case), it will make the browser render the field in a "disabled" fashion (greyed out background, etc..), and it won't fire events.

Readonly fields get included when the form is sent, and the browser will not apply any visual style to mark it as readonly, it will only prevent the user from modifying the value.

On a side note, only XHTML disallows attribute minification so `<input disabled="disabled">` is only required if you're writting XHTML and not for HTML4.01 or HTML5 where `<input disabled>` or `<input readonly>` is the correct way of using boolean attributes.